# How to draw Polylines with Arrowheads in Google Maps Android?

Tags: android, maps, google-polyline

I am developing an app to track vehicles. I get `LatLng` data's from a device fitted on the vehicle. Then I plot the `LatLng`'s on map and draw `Polyline` between them. That's working fine. I get the following output.
[image]

The problem is that I want to show the direction in which the vehicle traveled. I surfed through the Internet but couldn't find a solution. So please anyone guide me on how to draw arrow head in Polylines to show the direction. Thank you.

Comment: Do vehicle transmit its location using mobile device?

Comment: No it has a physical device fitted to the vehicle. The  device will send location of the vehicle each minute when vehicle travles @MuhammadBabar

Comment: Does the device can determine and send bearing (heading) of the vehicle?

Comment: It just `LatLng` only. But I found a solution by calculating bearing between one first location and next and rotated my marker to that bearing,

Answer (score 0):

[Arrow Mark over Polyline in Android Google Route Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274920/arrow-mark-over-polyline-in-android-google-route-map)

Also, since you probably get `Location` from the GPS, and not `LatLng` you can use `Location.bearingTo`